# package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path for centos

Tags: opencv, centos, pkg-config

When I go with this command:

```
 pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

I get the following message:

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

I'm on Cent OS 6, have found the solution for Linux Ubuntu over the internet and here on stack but not for Cent OS

I tried under OpenCV specifications with

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/share/opencv/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Still it doesn't work. How can I be sure OpenCV is also installed in that directory, I used whereis opencv and it triggered me `/usr/share/`

Answer (score 2):

I know it is really late to answer to a question 4 years later but I will leave it here in hope that it will help someone.

I came also across a similar error after installing OpenCV 3.3.0 on Fedora 26. First, make sure you have the right path to your opencv.pc file. Mine is in this directory '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/'.

Run this command in your terminal. It will modify your `.bashrc`:

```
echo "#ADD OpenCV in PKG_CONFIG" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then execute:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: If they add those lines directly to their bashrc, it will edit itself every time it is run. I presume you mean to run the lines you provided, once, in order to edit the bashrc.

Comment: What I mean is, the user should either manually add `#ADD OpenCV in PKG_CONFIG`, `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}` and `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to their bashrc, or they should execute the lines you provided. Adding your lines directly to their bashrc would not be wise, as the lines themselves modify the bashrc whenever they are run.

Answer (score -3):

Hi first of all i would like you to use 'Synaptic Package Manager'. You just need to goto the ubuntu software center and search for synaptic package manager.. The beauty of this is that all the packages you need are easily available here. Second it will automatically configures all your paths. Now install this then search for opencv packages over there if you found the package with the green box then its installed but else the package is not in the right place so you need to reinstall it but from package manager this time. If installed then you can do this only, you just need to fill the OpenCV_DIR variable with the path of opencv (containing the OpenCVConfig.cmake file)

```
export OpenCV_DIR=<path_of_opencv>
```

Comment: Op is in CentOS not ubuntu